# Inserting Date from form using PHP Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I can not seem to get the date to insert from my form into my data base. Please help!

here is my form

```
echo '

<h1>Enter New Report</h1>
<form action="submitreport.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">

 Date: <input type="text" name="Date" value='.$myDate.' /><br />
 Report:<br><TEXTAREA NAME=Report ROWS=4 COLS=40></TEXTAREA><br />
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>

 ';
 ?>
```

Here is what I have written to submit it to the database

```
$insertdate = trim($_POST['Date']);

$insertdate = mysql_real_escape_string($insertdate);
    $insertdate = date('m/d/Y', $insertdate);

echo $insertdate;


mysql_query("INSERT INTO `Reports`(`Date`, `Report`) VALUES ('$insertdate','$_POST[Report]')") or die("load1 -" .  mysql_error());


mysql_close();

echo "Thank You!" . " -" . "<a href='index.php' style='text-decoration:none;color:#ff0099;'> Return Home</a>";
?>
```

Comment: What format is the Date field in your database?

Comment: Where is the `$myDate` variable defined?

Comment: does $myDate contain timestamp? otherwise `date` function will return false or raise a WARNING message. use [`strtotime`](http://am.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) when passing parameter to `date`

Comment: What half-assed book/site taught you `mysql_query`?  It's been (at least unofficially) deprecated for years now.  Check out PDO and mysqli.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm only guessing, but your `Date` field in the database is either of type `date` or `datetime`. The format of these are `YYYY-mm-dd`. Try changing your code to:

```
$insertdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['Date']));
```

Also, you aren't converting the date to a timestamp before formatting it. I've added `strtotime()` on the data here as well.

Comment: It's the same as what you posted in your answer (except all in one line), so I should hope it works too =P

Answer (score 2):

PHP's `date` needs a timestamp as second parameter. If `$insertdate` isn't one it won't work. You can though get a timestamp from a string using PHP's `strtotime()` function.

Also, the value in your sql statement must be formatted according to the type used in your mysql database, for example `date`, `datetime` or `timestamp`

Comment: I still do not know why the default of mysql is Y-m-d but changing the format of my date and using the strtotime() function fixed the problem.

Comment: Actually, the second parameter to `date()` is optional - without one, it will give you the current date/time. *If* you specify one it needs to be a Unix-timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NOW() MySQL function to insert the current date/time into the database.  You'll just need to be using the Date, DateTime or Timestamp field types for this to work.

Comment: I was using the date('m/d/Y') function just to put todays date in the form however I needed it to be allowed editing.

Answer (score 0):

I got it 
     $insertdate = trim($_POST['Date']);

```
$insertdate = mysql_real_escape_string($insertdate);
$insertdate = strtotime($insertdate);

    $insertdate = date('Y-m-d', $insertdate);
```

The strtotime fixed it but I had to rearrange the  date format to Y-m-d

Thank you for the help